# How to use emplace/insert_or_assign in nested map with c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

If I have

```
map<int, map<int, int>> m;
```

And when I need to insert, I could use

```
m[1] = { {1, 1} };
```

But now I want to use emplace/insert_or_assign to replace it, I may use

```
m.emplace(1, map<int, int>{ {1, 1} });
```

But I think it is a bit complex to write, expecially I should write `map<int, int>`again,
even more if the original map change into such as `map<int, map<int, map<int, map<int, int>>>>`, then I should repeat `map<int, int>` as much as it need.
So is there any more simple and readable method?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your need? The reason I'm asking is because `emplace` and `insert_or_assign` have different behaviors. The behavior of `emplace` is closer to `insert` whereas `insert_or_assign` is closer to using `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The question should be why do you want to use `emplace`/`insert_or_assign` at the first point.

---

The point of `emplace` is so that you don't do unnecessary creation until it is needed. With a `map<int, map<int, int>>`, you might want to create the inner map only if you are going to insert the new map. To properly utilize such behavior, you should only supply the arguments that construct the map, not the map itself.

However, the only constructor `map` has that can also fill the container during construction is the one taking an `initializer_list`. So ideally you would want to write something like:

```cpp
m.emplace(1, {{1, 1}}) // this won't work
```

However, this wouldn't work because there's no way for `emplace` to deduce `{{1, 1}}` as a `initializer_list`. Which means you have to specify that manually like:

```cpp
m.emplace(1, std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, int>>{{1, 1}})
```

That's quite some writing, which will only be worse if you have more nested layers. At this point it's probably better to just write:

```cpp
if (m.find(1) == m.end()) {
// or `!m.contains(1)` for C++20 or later
    m[1] = {{1, 1}};
}
```

On the other hand, if you didn't really care about the unnecessary construction, you should just use `insert` instead:

```cpp
m.insert({1, {{1, 1}}})
```

---

The point of `insert_or_assign` is to make map works on types that is not default constructible.

When you just call `m[1]`, this will default construct an object if `m[1]` does not exist. However, that also means `operator[]` does not work if the type is not default constructible.

However, since a `map` is default constructible, there isn't much difference between using `operator[]` directly and using `insert_or_assign`. So instead, just go use `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
typedef map<int, int> mp;
```

and then do

```
m.emplace(1, mp{ {1, 1} });
```

That's less verbose and also clearly indicates what is map constructor and what  isn't.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: You can also try doing

```
template <typename T>
using nest_mp = std::map<int, T>;

typedef std::map<int, int> mp;
```

and do

```
m.emplace(1, nest_mp<nest_mp<mp>>>{ {1, { {1, { {1, 1} } } } } };
```

There are two `{` braces for each map construction - one to invoke the `std::map` initializer list constructor, the other to invoke the `std::pair` initializer list constructor.

Comment: Just wondering what compiler are your using? `m.emplace(1, { {1, 1} });` shouldn't work.

Comment: If you go to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map, they give you an example of the initializer list constructor. The syntax seems pretty similar to what I wrote IMO.
The map initializer list constructor was introduced in C++11 if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, there is a constructor with an `initializer_list`, however when you put it in `emplace`, it cannot deduce the type without specifying it is an `initializer_list<some_type>`. Which mean you need to write something like `m.emplace(1, std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, int>>{{1, 1}})` manually.

Comment: I see what you mean. My mistake. In that case, you can go with the typedef method. I think it's the better practice for clarity anyhow. I'll edit my response accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better not to use `map<int, map<int, int>>` at all.  Instead, use `map<std::pair<int, int>, int`.  This means you have a composite key, so instead of storing a value at `[A][B]` you store it at `[pair(A, B)]`.  This way when you store a value it's always a single memory allocation for its node (because there's just one map).

Then you write code like this:

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair(1, 1), 1);
m.insert_or_assign({1, 1}, 1);
```

And if you want to iterate the values with a specific "first" integer in the key:

```
int subkey = 1;
for (auto it = m.lower_bound({subkey, 0}),
    end = m.upper_bound({subkey, INT_MAX});
    it != end; ++it)
{
    // do something with elements whose key.first == subkey
}
```